# Any Eigenvectors of $\lambda$ in $\mathrm{range\;} T-\lambda I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading the Linear Algebra Done Right textbook by Axler, and an extension stemming from 5.27's proof 1 has been troubling me. This is a closer look into the book’s construction of $U$, an invariant subspace. I wanna find out if:

Given linear operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ with $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue, we define $U = \mathrm{range\;}(T - \lambda I)$. If $\dim U > 0$, then does there exist a $\lambda$-eigenvector $v \in U$? In other words, does there exist nonzero $v \in U$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$?

Thank you in advance, and any intuition is appreciated.

Comment: you mean some $u \neq 0$? Then no in general for take $T = I$ and $\lambda = 1$, then $T-\lambda I = 0$ and $\text{range}(T-\lambda I ) = 0$?

Comment: @psl2Z That's right, thank you for the correction.

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you for your corrections! First post here, quite nervous.

Comment: Well, @psl2Z answered your question, didn't (s)he?

Comment: @AnneBauval I was wondering, what if the dimension of $\mathrm{range\;} T-\lambda I$ is larger than 0. Then, is the answer still no?

Again, thank you for your patience.

Comment: Letting $S=T-\lambda I$, what you are asking is whether if $\ker S$ and $\operatorname{im}S$ are $\ne\{0\}$, so is their intersection. You should easily find a counterexample (think of projections).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)

Comment: @AnneBauval I see, I'm indeed trying to show if kernel and image of $(T-\lambda I)$ both non-$\{0\}$, then so is their intersection. However, could you show me how the projection idea works?

Thank you.

Comment: The intersection of range and kernel of a projection $S$ is $\{0\}$. Take any projection other than $0$ and $I$, choose any scalar $\lambda$, then $T:=S+\lambda I$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! This is great, and solved my problem.